# Python 2.7 PyTesseract AttributeError: 'PixelAccess' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, ocr, pytesser

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Stuff\imagetotext.py", line 9, in <module>
    i = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 143, in
image_to_string
    if len(image.split()) == 4:
AttributeError: 'PixelAccess' object has no attribute 'split'
```

So, I'm really not sure what to do with this. https://gyazo.com/63c6439285d629c72e9076c1b4a29a42 is test.png. I've tried a lot.

```
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

img = Image.open('test.bmp').load()
#img.load()
i = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print i
```

I've read it might be a bug with PIL, but I just have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

img = Image.open('test.bmp')
img.load()
i = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print i
```

Comment: WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: It is in the same folder.

Comment: I think you don't have tesseract installed.

Comment: I do, it imports fine.

Comment: I am not talking about pytesseract, it is just a wrapper. You need tesseract installed in your system. Can you check in your command line if tesseract is there? like "tesseract image.tif image"